# Why does changing the value of 'x' in the parent class only change the value of one child?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, theory

Whilst experimenting with python, I realised that this code does not produce the output I expected :

```
class Parent(object):
    x = 1

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    pass


print Parent.x, Child1.x, Child2.x

Child1.x = 2
print Parent.x, Child1.x, Child2.x

Parent.x = 3
print Parent.x, Child1.x, Child2.x
```

The output of the above code is :

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
3 2 3
```

Why is the output of the last line `3 2 3` rather than `3 2 1`? Why does changing the value of Parent.x also change the value of Child2.x, but at the same time not change the value of Child1.x?

Thanks

Comment: Because you changed the value of `x` to 3 ie `Parent.x = 3`.. where child2 get the x from parent.

Comment: if you remove Child1.x = 2 it would be 3 3 3
but since you have set it to the child it won't access the value of parent class anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assigned to `Child1.x`, you created a new attribute for Child1 only. However, Child2 does not have its own `x` attribute, so it inherits Parent's version, whatever the current value of that is.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of properties defined in class Python has copy-on-write behaviour. As every variable in Python is a reference, until you assign new value to `Child1.x` the `x` in `Child1` refers to the value of `Parent.x`.

In fact what you're trying to do is in general bad practice! You shouldn't place with class defined variables you plan to amend later until you **REALLY** know what you're doing. In fact your example is *abuse* of object oriented paradigm, because you should play with instances of your classes, not classes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

A more extended answer as in the comment
if you add this to the end of your script

```
print Parent.__dict__
print Child1.__dict__
print Child2.__dict__
```

you get a detailed look about all members of the class and what is stored into them. 
The output will be

```
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Parent' objects>, 'x': 3,    '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Parent' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{'x': 2, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

As you can see in child1
'x': 2
was added to the dict. So child1 does not look for the value in it's parent class but child2 does